# This SlidingMenu appears to already be attached Android

Tags: android, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

I getting following error

**This SlidingMenu appears to already be attached**

This my source code

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

I have used [sliding menu library by jfeinstein](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

I want to slide menu with `actionbar`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

From the SlidingMenu.java in attachToActivity method

```
if (getParent() != null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("This SlidingMenu appears to already be attached");
```

here getParent is not null because you already assigned SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW when you create object of SlidingMenu.

e.g. `SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);`

above line of code calls attachToActivity. see in code

```
public SlidingMenu(Activity activity, int slideStyle) {
    this(activity, null);
    this.attachToActivity(activity, slideStyle);
}
```

So you are adding menu to layout twice. And that is the cause of problem.

**Solution**  use one of the following.

1. Use below constructor

   SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);

OR

2. remove menu.attachToActivity(); line

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question.
There is a R.java file in  com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib,you might miss it.
You can copy it from other SlidingMenu project into gen folder.